# PG bouncer running on vm instance stops connecting to cloud sql

Tags: postgresql, terraform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

The issue:

I'm not sure how to begin problem solving this or where to look for errors.

Setup:
Running a node.js backend via GCR and it's hitting a postgres db on cloud sql through a GCE vm with pg bouncer to handle connection pooling.

Every once in a while, I’ll get hit with a ‘unable to reach the db’ error.  It happens once every 1-2 months and I’m not sure what’s causing it.

When it does happen, I have to re-terraform the pgbouncer vm to be able to connect to my db again.

I used this terraform module: [cloud-sql-pgbouncer](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/christippett/cloud-sql-pgbouncer/google/latest)

Comment: Without logs, how do you expect this can be triaged? You don't see error logs on the container running on GCR or the GCE VM?

Comment: Thanks that's all I needed, Idk why I didn't have logging enabled. I guess I'll just wait until it happens again and see what the issue is.

Comment: Enabled logging on GCE and will be waiting until it happens again to see what the issue is.

Comment: Off topic, but could you share how are you hitting pgbouncer from a Cloud Run service?